# MySQL and PHP Basic Form Echo

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am a beginner PHP coder.  I want it to be if when they register for my php code, it echos "You have been registered", instead of just showing a blank page.  This is my code:

```
<?php
    require('config.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      //Preform the verification of the nation
      $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
      $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
      $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
      $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

      if($email1 == $email2) {
         if($pass1 == $pass2) {
           //All good.  Carry on.

            $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
            $lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
            $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
            $email1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email1']);
            $email2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email2']);
            $pass1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
            $pass2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);
            $pass1 = md5($pass1);

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$uname'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
                 echo "Sorry, that user already exists!";
                 exit();
             }
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, 
                         `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$name',  '$lname',  '$uname',  '$email1',  
                         '$pass1')");

           }else{
               echo "Sorry, your passwords do not match<br><br>";
               exit();
         }
     }else{
        echo "Sorry, your emails do not match.<br><br>";
    }
   }else{
    $form = <<<EOT
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /><br />
    Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br />
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
    </form>
    EOT;
    echo $form;
   }
?>
```

As you can see, there is no echo for if everything works.  Please help me add an echo if they're registrations gets registered!!

Comment: tip: don't check for the presence of a form field to figure out if a post occured. it's unreliable. use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ... }` instead. it's 100% reliable and will never fail you.

Comment: By the way, md5 is NOT a way to create "Secure" user passwords.  It's a cheap way and is easily uncryptable.  Please check into using [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)  This will ensure a more secure environment.  Don't learn the hard way

Comment: make sure it gets inserted into db, then display  the message!

Answer (score 0):

Just check the return of the insert query.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT ...");
if ($result) {
    echo "Created!";
} else {
    echo "Uh oh!  Something went wrong!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case - You could just type:

```
echo "Congratulations, You've been submitted";
```

or whatever you want to say just under the insert statement

Answer (score 0):

before the last

```
}else{
```

in your code put

```
echo "You have signed up";
```

and that's it :)